# Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-212]

Tags: hibernate, h2

I was Debugging my Java Code, but now I'm getting this error. Earlier also it happened to me and I used to delete the process but Now I'm not able to find the process id and also All the connections are closed. I'm not sure what is causing the issue.
Also Got this message:
`Caused by:  org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: The file is locked: C:/test/deploy_center.mv.db [2.1.212/7`

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: @all Does anyone went get this Issue ??